# MYSQL foreign key to the same table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with following columns: "`id`, `parent_id`, `name`" , where `parent_id` points to a entity in the same table.

I want to add a constraint that stops me from deleting an entity, if there are other entities, that have the first one as `parent_id`.

Can a foreign key be used for this or is foreign key only allowed to point to other tables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a foreign key can reference the same table.

A classic example of this, often included in the sample database that comes with the database, is:

```
create table employee (
    id int not null primary key,
    manager_id int not null references employee,
    ...
)
```

Such references are known as *self-referencing* foreign keys. If defined like the above,they automatically prevent deletion of a "parent" record if there are "children" that reference it.